# sprintf bloginfo odditie

Tags: localization, bloginfo

Why the *disco funk* this is happening I can't quite put my finger on - but I guarantee you it's because I'm probably missing some simple PHP best-practice:

```
<?php echo '<h3>' . sprintf(__('Welcome to %s', 'roots'), bloginfo('name')) . '</h3>'; ?>
```

For some reason outputs:

```
Site Name<h3>Welcome to </h3>
```

Any light nudges in the right direction would be really appreciated - and maybe a slap on the head once I figure out what's going on ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`get_bloginfo()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo) instead of [`bloginfo()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo). The former *returns* the value; the latter *echoes* the value.

Comment: Lowers head in shame... but gives @Chip a high-five. Thanks, really appreciate it!